# Get Icy metadata from audio stream with Exoplayer2 without using duplicate streams

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I thought I found a way to do this, but it seems like this is for exoplayer1 (the first answer to this question):  [Extracting metadata from Icecast stream using Exoplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125471/extracting-metadata-from-icecast-stream-using-exoplayer)

I already have a way to read Icy metadata, but it uses a stream of it's own, so it creates extra data costs for the user.

How can this be done just using one instance of the stream?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by registering a listener for your ExoPlayer instance:

```
exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onMediaMetadataChanged(MediaMetadata mediaMetadata) {
        String title = (String)mediaMetadata.title; // This is the artist / song
    }
}
```